# Does Windows 10 Technical Preview require support for PAE, NX, and SSE2?

Tags: windows-10-preview

According to [Microsoft's website](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-faq#faq=tab1), the system requirements for the Windows 10 Technical Preview state that a 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster CPU is required. However, it doesn't say anything about PAE, NX, and SSE2, just like the [Windows 8 system requirements](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/system-requirements). Did Microsoft remove this requirement, or is it still in place but not mentioned?

Comment: **The requirements for Windows 10 are Windows 8's requirements**.  This has been stated by Microsoft.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [System Requirements for Windows 10 Preivew](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/preview-faq#faq=tab1):

> "Basically, if your PC can run Windows 8.1, you’re good to go."

From the [Windows 8(.1) system requirements](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/system-requirements):

> If you want to run Windows 8.1 on your PC, here's what it takes:
>
> - Processor: 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster **with support for PAE, NX, and SSE2**
> - RAM: 1 gigabyte (GB) (32-bit) or 2 GB (64-bit)
> - Hard disk space: 16 GB (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit)
> - Graphics card: Microsoft DirectX 9 graphics device with WDDM driver

So just like Windows 8.1, you'll need those CPU features to be able to run Windows 10.

Comment: +1 They're unlikely to *ever* reduce requirements

Comment: @Tetsujin Exactly. :)